# Disable f3 search IE 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-events

I'm trying to simulate some software in a browser window for training purposes. When the user presses <kbd>f3</kbd> I need it to go back to the prior page instead of opening the search dialogue in IE7. I've tried the following code but I receive:

> An error has occuredError: 78 Permission Denied

Any ideas?

```
$('#command').keydown(function(e) {     
    if(e.which === 114) {
        e = 0;
        history.go(-1);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the redirect to the `keyup` handler and simply `return false;` from the `keydown` handler. Returning false from the `keydown` event will cause the built in handler to not fire, then the `keyup` event will redirect.

```
$('#command').keydown(function(e) {  
    if(e.which === 114) {
         return false;   
    }
});

$('#command').keyup(function(e) {  
    if(e.which === 114) {
         history.go(-1); 
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CUDaR/4/

Comment: I see return false; alot and return true; as well but being fairly new to coding I don't really understand what this does with the exception of knowing that return false; seems to prevent page reload sometimes.

Comment: Returning false from a JavaScript event causes it to not perform the default action of that event. In this case opening the search box.

Comment: so returning true would tell the JavaScript to perform the default action of that event...so theoretically you would always want to say return false for an "if" statement if you don't have a corresponding "else" statement. Thereby saying IF NOT TRUE...Do nothing. Right?